# Change active state of nav item on scorll and a slieght problem with it

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a navbar and a few section and want to change the active state of the nav items as I scroll over the sections.

I have the following code:

```js
var sections = $('section')
, nav = $('nav')
, nav_height = nav.outerHeight();

$(window).on('scroll', function () {
var cur_pos = $(this).scrollTop();

sections.each(function() {
  var top = $(this).offset().top - nav_height,
      bottom = top + $(this).outerHeight();

  if (cur_pos >= top && cur_pos <= bottom) {
    nav.find('a').removeClass('active');
    sections.removeClass('active');

    $(this).addClass('active');
    nav.find('a[href="#'+$(this).attr('id')+'"]').addClass('active');
  }
});
});
```

```html
<header>
        <section id="home">
        <nav>
<div class="nav-container">
               
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#home" class="active">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#service">Service</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
             </nav>
    </section>
    </header>
    
    <section id="service"></section>
    
    <section id="contact"></section>
```

When I scroll down it works fine. When I scroll up almost fine because when I get back to the home section it does not get the active state again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got your nav inside of the Home Section.

So when you hit here:

```
var top = $(this).offset().top - nav_height,
```

Your offset from the top is `0` and when you do your check `if (cur_pos >= top && cur_pos <= bottom)` your `cur_pos` is `-{navBarHeight}`

Try moving your nav outside and above of the home section, or take that into account.